# Cast out [downcasting]

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, retag-request

Is there a need for [downcasting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/downcasting) when we have [casting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/casting)?

Comment: They're not *exactly* the same I guess, since *downcasting* is explicitly reduced to base-to-derived conversions.

Answer (score 5):

There are lots and lots and lots of different notions of casting.

1. Converting something from one type to another in some canonical fashion, such as turning an integer into its decimal representation.
2. Treating memory viewed by the type system as representing something of one type and forcing it to view it as something of another type.
3. Checking whether something has a particular type based on dynamic information and treating it accordingly.

Downcasting, in contrast, has a fairly specific meaning, a well-defined case of (3), in which an object known to be an instance of a superclass of a particular class is checked to see if it is an instance of that class and treated accordingly. As an *unambiguous* tag in a realm full of ambiguous terminology, it is particularly valuable and should not be burned.